# How to use nested for in clojure

Tags: clojure

I have a list of lists,`((1,2,3,4)(2,3,4,5)(3,4,5,6))` and I want to implement for loop in clojure. I want to first get the first list i.e, `(1,2,3,4)` and then again implement for loop in this to get each element.

Thank you

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking for. The clojure `for` macro doesn't have identical semantics to what other languages call `for`, so without knowing how you're going to use the result, it's impossible to say whether any given solution actually accomplishes what you want.

Comment: don't quite understand the requirement either

Comment: You probably need (eventually nested) 'reduce' or (eventually nested) 'loop recur' for specific work

Answer (score 1):

1. Clojure's `for` is *not* a looping structure.
2. It is a *macro* that generates a combination of the necessary nested
   `map`, `filter`, and `take-while` calls. These operate on *sequences*.
3. It always produces a *lazy sequence*.

From your question, I infer that you make sense of (1), but make nothing of (2) or (3). If you want to use Clojure effectively, understand their terms, and your question will answer itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop through all the numbers as if they were in one list you can `flatten` the list:

```
> (flatten `((1,2,3,4)(2,3,4,5)(3,4,5,6)))
(1 2 3 4 2 3 4 5 3 4 5 6)
```

After that, to do an action against all the numbers you could use any function that takes in a list of numbers. Here's an example using `reduce` and `+`:

```
> (reduce + (flatten `((1,2,3,4)(2,3,4,5)(3,4,5,6))))
42
```

Answer (score -4):

A `for` expression is meant to transform a collection into another collection, which is the return value. A  `doseq` expression is meant to have side effects and always returns `nil`.

Here is some example code & results. Note that I usually prefer `forv` instead of `for`, as `forv` is not lazy and always returns results in a vector.

```
(ns xyz
  (:require  [tupelo.core :as t] ))
(t/refer-tupelo)

(def data
 '[ (1,2,3,4)
    (2,3,4,5)
    (3,4,5,6) ] )

(newline)
(println "forv demo")
(spyx (forv [i [1 2 3]]
  (spyx i )))

(newline)
(println "doseq demo")
(spyx (doseq [i [1 2 3]]
  (spyx i )))

(println "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------")
(newline)
(println "for 1d")
(println "final result ="
  (forv [sub-list data]
    (spyx sub-list )))

(newline)
(println "for 2d")
(println "final result ="
  (forv [sub-list  data
         int-val   sub-list]
    (spyx int-val )))
(newline)

(newline)
(println "for 2d-2")
(println "final result ="
  (forv [sub-list  data]
    (forv [int-val   sub-list]
      (spyx int-val ))))
(newline)

(println "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------")
(newline)
(println "doseq 1d")
(doseq [sub-list data]
  (println  "sub-list =" sub-list ))

(newline)
(println "doseq 2d")
(doseq [sub-list  data]
  (doseq [int-val sub-list]
    (spyx int-val )))

(newline)
(println "doseq 2d-2")
(doseq [sub-list  data
        int-val   sub-list]
    (spyx int-val ))
```

The first shows that both loop over data, but `for`/`forv` return a new collection, while `doseq` returns `nil` and is only intended for side effects.

```
forv demo
i => 1
i => 2
i => 3
(forv [i [1 2 3]] (spyx i)) => [1 2 3]

doseq demo
i => 1
i => 2
i => 3
(doseq [i [1 2 3]] (spyx i)) => nil
```

The second part shows how `for` can be used for 1-d or 2-d loops. Also, a single `forv` statement can to 2-d looping, or you can nest the `forv` statements. Notice the difference in nesting in the final result for the 3 cases.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

for 1d
sub-list => (1 2 3 4)
sub-list => (2 3 4 5)
sub-list => (3 4 5 6)
final result = [(1 2 3 4) (2 3 4 5) (3 4 5 6)]

for 2d
int-val => 1
int-val => 2
int-val => 3
int-val => 4
int-val => 2
int-val => 3
int-val => 4
int-val => 5
int-val => 3
int-val => 4
int-val => 5
int-val => 6
final result = [1 2 3 4 2 3 4 5 3 4 5 6]


for 2d-2
int-val => 1
int-val => 2
int-val => 3
int-val => 4
int-val => 2
int-val => 3
int-val => 4
int-val => 5
int-val => 3
int-val => 4
int-val => 5
int-val => 6
final result = [[1 2 3 4] [2 3 4 5] [3 4 5 6]]

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The `doseq` syntax is similar to `for`, but only the side effects like `print` are visible to the outside world.  `doseq` always returns `nil`. This also implies there is no nesting difference in the return value like with `forv`.

```
doseq 1d
sub-list = (1 2 3 4)
sub-list = (2 3 4 5)
sub-list = (3 4 5 6)

doseq 2d
int-val => 1
int-val => 2
int-val => 3
int-val => 4
int-val => 2
int-val => 3
int-val => 4
int-val => 5
int-val => 3
int-val => 4
int-val => 5
int-val => 6

doseq 2d-2
int-val => 1
int-val => 2
int-val => 3
int-val => 4
int-val => 2
int-val => 3
int-val => 4
int-val => 5
int-val => 3
int-val => 4
int-val => 5
int-val => 6
```

Note that your `project.clj` will need to include the following for `spyx` to work

:dependencies [
    [tupelo "0.9.10"]